# Android SIP - How disconnect from SIP Server

Tags: android, sip, disconnection

I'm using the code explained [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html) (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html)
and my test SIP server is [OfficeSIP](http://www.officesip.com/)

The connection is ok, but whe i try to make disconnection with this lines code

```
public void closeLocalProfile() {
    if (mSipManager == null) {
       return;
    }
    try {
       if (mSipProfile != null) {
          mSipManager.close(mSipProfile.getUriString());
       }
     } catch (Exception ee) {
       Log.d("WalkieTalkieActivity/onDestroy", "Failed to close local profile.", ee);
     }
}
```

The server seems that doesn't disconnect the account (even if it is no longer reachable).

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just call the [unregister](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html#unregister(android.net.sip.SipProfile,%20android.net.sip.SipRegistrationListener)) API before to close:

```
mSipManager.unregister(mSipProfile,mylistener);
```

Comment: nothing.. I've written

'manager.close(me.getUriString());
manager.unregister(me, registrationListener);'

but it remains connected. Maybe it depend on auto-registration [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html#open(android.net.sip.SipProfile, android.app.PendingIntent, android.net.sip.SipRegistrationListener)) ? How can i disable it?

Comment: I think that you should make a network trace to see the actual packets because maybe the problem is on your server or your server doesn't understand the unregister message. When you call unregister, a REGISTER message should be sent with Expire set to 0.